# Is it possible to get the native iPod Touch and iPhone apps on the iPad?

Tags: iphone, applications, ipod-touch, ios, ipad

If like me you have an iPad and iPhone chances are you want some of the apps on both devices.

For some reason the iPad has lost some of the apps, notably, Clock, Calculator, Weather, and Voice Memos.

For me some of these are important, Clock gives me world times, a timer and alarms. Weather, tells e the weater (although I can look on the web) Caluclator helps out every now and then.

I am aware that there are apps which perform these functions on the app store, I am wondering however, Is it possible to get the native iPod Touch and iPhone apps on the iPad?

I would prefer this soultion as my homescreens will have the same app icons on. I am currently running iOS5 on all devices and have some of the third party apps.

Comment: Are you OK wiht jailbreaking?

Comment: Thanks for asking, I do not want to jailbreak.

Comment: As @bmike answered below, it is not possible without jailbreaking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since these apps are packaged as part of the Core iOS image, you will need to jailbreak the iPad OS to allow modification/installation of the apps currently shipped as part of the iPhone / iPod touch such as Calculator, Clock, etc...

The best technical description of /Applications on iOS is from [The iPhone Wiki](http://theiphonewiki.com/wiki/index.php?title=/Applications) where it calls out the differentiation between iOS images and major release versions. I haven't ever used it, but the [jailbreak package "Belfry"](http://iphoneblogr.com/2012/01/install-native-iphone-clock-stocks-weather-compass-calculator-and-voice-memos-on-ipad-with-belfry-cydia-tweak/) purports to do precisely what you ask and might make interesting reading as well in case you change your mind about jailbreaking in the future.

Answer (score 0):

On the new Apple stores, for iOS 7.0 and 8.0 I think, at the top there is an option to switch between "iPad only" apps and "iPhone only" apps.